# How can I check the position of an element on an array?

Tags: arrays, c, memory, struct, embedded

I've got the struct

```
struct timer_t;
```

and an array of those timer struct

```
timer_t timer[6];
```

I've also a callback function that takes as parameter an element of the array.

```
void timer_callback(timer_t *timer)
{
   //how can I check which position of the timer_t timer[6] is?
}
```

As you can see in the code, my question is how can I get the element position inside the array?
Need to know which element of the array is the *timer. I can get the array of the timers inside the callback function.
Thank you.

Comment: Umm, I think you would need to iterate over `timer[]` searching for desired atttribute.

Comment: Where is the array defined? Is it a local or global variable?

Comment: I can get the array inside the callback.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is _not_ give the array and the parameter the same symbol name, otherwise in `timer_callback()` `timer` will refer and the array will be inaccessible (shadowed).

Comment: could you register a _seperate callback_ just for `timer[6]`?

Answer (score 4):

If you're sure that the callback parameter points to an element of the array, then you can the index with simple pointer arithmetic: `idx = timer_ptr - timer_array`.

But if it doesn't point into the array, then this will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can't simply 'know' the position, you can either pass the array and iterate through it, or pass the index in which the element is in. Depending on either you know where the element is when you call the function or not, and will need to search for it.

Edit: if you have the array inside the function:

```
// you will need a different array name as to not conflict
int i = 0;
while (i < 6 && *timer != timer_array[i]) i++;

if (i != 6) {
    // timer found
}
```

Edit: I'd suggest a `#define ARRAY_SIZE 6` rather than a literal `6` all over the code. Or even worse a division of size like `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`.

Comment: I can get the array inside the callback. But then, how can I compare the elements?
Is this correct inside a loop?
        if(timer[i]==timer)
               break;
or 
        if(&timer[i]==&timer)
               break;
Being the final i the position of the element on the array.

Comment: Compare the content of the structure. `if (timer[i].something != timer.somthing && timer[i].somethingelse != timer.somethingelse ....)`. Or compare __the address__ of the elements. The "correctness" depends on semantics that _you want_ to have (does equality of elements means that the element content is the same? or does it mean it's exactly the same element?). I can only guess that comparing addresses `&timer_array[i] == timer` is what you want. Nothing will save you from understand it anyway - I suggest to start with a good C book instead.

Comment: I would suggest `sizeof(timer_array) / sizeof(*timer_array)` rather then a literal `6`.